# Calculating percentage of classes of raster present in cells of larger raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, overlay, summarizing

I have a Landcover raster layer at 25m resolution and would like to calculate the fraction of different classes within this layer present in each cell of a 1km resolution raster.

The diagram below illustrates what I'm looking to do. Taking for example the red class in the 25m raster, each cell in the 1km raster would have a value representing the fraction of that cell covered by the red class.

[image: Explanatory diagram]

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/435549/edit) to describe what you want as output (one raster/band per 25m colour, or table of values).